# error: cannot open source file "winrt/WIndows.Foundation" showed up when I follow a microsoft's tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-winrt

I'm a complete beginner in Visual Studio and C++.
And now, I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--setting-up-the-games-infrastructure) tutorial by Microsoft.

So I installed "c++/WinRT templates and visualizer" in my Visual Studio 2019 from the "Extension" menu above the visual studio and created a core app project.

However, when I run the project, visual Studio shows up lots of errors like "cannot open source file "winrt/Windows.Foundation.h".(I tried to follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--setting-up-the-games-infrastructure#tidy-up-the-project)
)

[image]
[image]

I suspect that these errors are environment variable issues.
But I don't have any idea of where I should change.

Currently, I install Visual Studio in D drive and create the project in D drive. But there's a possibility that other required software like windows SDK(?) are installed in C Drive.

If there is other information required to solve these errors, I'm willing to add it to this post.

I'm terribly stuck here(like a lost child). I'm not sure even asking this question here is acceptable.
But if you help me, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: C++/WinRT was added to the Windows SDK starting in build 17025. If you have an older SDK, the pregenerated header files won't be there. You can nevertheless generate them yourself. You can also [download the finished product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/simple3dgamedx/) to confirm that your environment is set up properly.

Comment: All of those errors are IntelliSense errors, designated by the `E` prefix (compiler errors have a `C` prefix). You get those for every new C++/WinRT project, until you compile at least once. The build system installs the *CppWinRT* NuGet package that provides the code generator (*cppwinrt.exe*). It is the code generator that generates the required header files into a *Generated Files* subdirectory of your source tree. Try compiling the code and see if you can find the generated header files (such as *winrt/base.h*).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you! I download the finished product and confirm that my environment was wrong! Now I noticed that my winrt is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10` so I add the path to my project and it works!

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the information! Now I made a new project file and worked well after the compiling! And I found generated files in the subdirectory! Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't add the C++/WinRT header files provided by the SDK if you're using the NuGet package. The NuGet package generates the files for you, including all bug fixes that were added since the C++/WinRT SDK header files were published (almost 3 years ago).

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @IInspectable said in the comment, I need to compile my codes at least once　when I create C++/winRT project.
After I compile my project, NuGet package generates C++/winRT headers automatically!